# How to change the Contributed to Saved?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to inquire about the google map app. How to change the Contributed to Saved?

I can not find a place that can contact with Google for a week.

I just change iphone to samsung, then the issue happend.

I hope ther's a engineer from google can found this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.